# When is the scope of a function called from a C++ function template determined? (MSVC)

Tags: c++, templates, scope, visual-studio-2022, msvc14

Given the following test code:

```
void Serialize(std::ostream& os, int& i)
{
    os << "int: " << i << '\n';
}

template<typename T>
void Write(std::ostream& os, T* pData)
{
    ::Serialize(os, *pData);
}

struct SData
{
    int i = 42;
};

void Serialize(std::ostream& os, SData& rData)
{
    os << "SData: " << rData.i << '\n';
}

void Test()
{
    auto os = std::ofstream("c:/test.out");
    auto s = SData();
    Write(os, &s);
}

int main([[maybe_unused]] int, [[maybe_unused]] char*[])
{
    Test();
}
```

The MSVC compiler with `/permissive-` (compiler set to standards conformance mode) fails to compile this as only the `Serialize` free function(s) declared prior to the the function template definition are visible to the function template.

The above compiles fine with the MSVC compiler either using `/permissive` (standards conformance mode disabled) or removing the global scope operator on the `Serialize` call.

The above also compiles fine when using the LLVM (clang-cl) toolset in VS 2022, or using clang++.

I would expect that the lookup occurs at the point that the function template is instantiated, and it appears that this is not the case with MSVC using `/permissive-`. Microsoft replied to my community post that this is not a bug. I'd like to know why this is expected behavior.

Comment: This has been explained by msvc team in their blogpost. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/

Comment: A very informative link. Thanks, that MS devblog post has an almost identical code example to what I cobbled together.

Answer (score 1):

Normal qualified and unqualified name lookup is done from the point-of-definition of the template. Only argument-dependent lookup (ADL) is done from the point-of-instantiation of the template specialization (if the call is dependent).

You are using a qualified call `::Serialize(os, *pData);` and qualified calls suppress ADL. Therefore it will never consider `Serialize` overloads declared later.

If you remove `::` then the call becomes unqualified and ADL will be done from the point-of-instantiation, which recursively from the implicit instantiation from `Write(os, &s);` in `Test` are two possible points in this case: One directly after the definition of `Test` and one after the the end of the translation unit. In either case because `SData` is an argument type to the call and because the `void Serialize(std::ostream& os, SData& rData)` overload is in the same namespace scope as `SData`, declared before the point-of-instantiation, it will be found by ADL.